# Xcode UI how to get the corresponding storyboard element?

Tags: xcode

What is the short cut to get the correspondign storyboard elements when selecting one of the black dots on the left of the code interface?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply click on that black dot, you can see the corresponding storyboard element. By selecting that, you can go directly to that particular view.

[image: Like this!]

Comment: when I click xcode sets a breakpoint? Should I use a combo keys?

Comment: No, just click inside that particular black dot itself. No keys required.